# A fast and efficient way to test if a set is subset of any other n sets?

Tags: performance, binary, set, subset, combinations

I have the following problem: I have a list of items

```
[O_0,..., O_n]
```

, where each item is represented by a binary power (o_0 represented by 2^0, ..., o_n by 2^n). I have constructed a list of combinations of these elements (each combination is represented by the sum of the binary representations of the items). For example I have

```
combs = [3, 9, 15, ......].
```

Given a new combination of these items say C_1, I would like to test if any of the elements of `combs` is included in `C_1`. An efficient and fast way that I thought of was to compute for each element `c_i from combs`, test if `c_i & C_1 == c_i` which means that it is true for this element. It is fast since I am doing a bitiwise and.
My problem is that instead of having 1 element `C_1`, I have a very big number of them `C_1, ..., C_k`, and I have to test for each one of them the above condition. SO I was wondering if there are any faster ways than the one I mentioned to test the condition of all of the elements (this is actually the same problem as testing if a set is a subset of another, which is why i chose binary representation from the beginning to transform the problem into a binary one).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the problem: given a collection of `k` sets `Y` and a collection of `m` sets `X`, we would like to find a subset `S` of `Y` such that for all `y in S`, there exists `x in X` s.t. `x` is a subset of `y`.

I will assume that sets are represented by `n`-vectors of zeros and ones denoting inclusion. Here is the setup:

```
import pandas as pd # for drop_duplicates & benchmarks
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

n = 100 # 100 "atomic" elements
m = 1000 # small sets
k = 1000 # large sets
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(m, n))).drop_duplicates().values
Y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(k, n))).drop_duplicates().values
# For each row y in Y, we would like to check if there exists a row x in X
# s.t. x represents a subset of Y

def naive(Y, X):
  # O(k^2 + m^2) 
  for i, y in enumerate(Y):
    for x in X:
      found_subset = False
      if (x <= y).all():
        yield i
        found_subset = True
      if found_subset:
        break    

def naive_as_array(Y, X):
  return np.array(list(naive(Y, X)))
```

The `naive` function iterates over all pairs of sets that may satisfy the inclusion relation and short-circuits whenever appropriate. The runtime is `O(m + k)` where `m = len(combs)`.

As an alternative, we can consider the following recursive algorithm processing each element (from `1` to `n`) at a time:

```
def contains(Y, X):
  """
  Y : k x n indicator array specifying sets
  X : m x n indicator array specifying sets
  output: subset Z of [0..k-1] s.t. i in Z iff there exists x in X s.t.
  # x is a subset of Y[i]. Z is represented by a 1D numpy array.
  """
  k, n = Y.shape
  assert Y.shape[1] == X.shape[1]
  detected = np.zeros(k, dtype=np.bool)
  inds = np.arange(k)

  # utility to account for sets that already have a subset detected
  def account_for_detected(Y, inds):
    mask = ~detected[inds]
    Y = Y[mask]
    inds = inds[mask]
    return Y, inds

  # inductively reduce Y.shape[1] (==X.shape[1])
  def f(Y, X, inds):
    if Y.shape[0] == 0 or X.shape[0] == 0:
      # collection Y is empty; inculsions are impossible
      return
    # avoid redundant comparisons by dropping sets y in Y
    # if it is already known that y contains some element of X
    Y, inds = account_for_detected(Y, inds)
    if Y.shape[1] == 1:
      # Y and X are collections of singletons
      Y = np.ravel(Y)
      X = np.ravel(X)
      X_vals = np.zeros(2, dtype=np.int)
      X_vals[X] = 1
      if X_vals[0] > 0:
        detected[inds] = True
      elif X_vals[1] > 0:
        detected[inds[Y==1]] = True
      return
    else:
      # make a recursive call
      Ymask = Y[:,0] == 0
      Xmask = X[:,0] == 0
      # if x in X is a subset of y in Y, x[0] <= y[0]
      f(Y[Ymask,1:], X[Xmask,1:], inds[Ymask])
      # by now, detected is updated in the outer scope
      # process the remaining Y's
      f(Y[~Ymask,1:], X[:,1:], inds[~Ymask])
      # done

  # make call at root:
  f(Y, X, inds)

  # return indices
  return np.where(detected)[0]
```

At step `d` between `1` and `n`, we split sets `Y` into `Y0` and `Y1` where `Y0` contains sets in `Y` that do not contain element `d`, and `Y1` contains sets in `Y` that do contain element `d`. Similarly, we define `X0` and `X1`. A key observation is that sets in `X1` cannot occur as subsets of sets in `Y0`. Therefore, we can reduce the number of comparisons  in the recursive call.

Timings:

```
%timeit contains(Y, X)
%timeit naive_as_array(Y, X)
10 loops, best of 3: 185 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 2.39 s per loop
```

---

[image]